# int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter is retriving old files

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

We are facing quite a weird problem.

We have configured ftp inbound channel adapter in xml. It uses DefaultFtpSessionFactory, FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter and PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore. MetadataStore configuration is in another xml file.

Now, we get files once a week as configured. Suddenly it started to get files which are 9-10 months old. After 4-5 weeks it resumed fetching new files where it was left. Then again old files and back to new ones. This back and forth has been going for a while and always serially.

Furthermore, metadata file has not been updated in a while.

Remote files are not deleted but local files are moved to archive after processing.

Can you please throw any light on the possibilities?

**Edit**
After some more investigation, there seems to be problem with poller also.
int:poller has cron for every Friday at 11 PM.

The files are not transferred to local directory on every poll rather in bulk once on some months.

Poller picks 1 file as expected on every Friday and passes it to spring JobLauncher.

The expected behavior is that every Friday, 1 file will be transferred to local directory and then processed by JobLauncher. This file is written on the remote server very early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` only flushes to disk on a normal application close.

See `setFlushOnUpdate()` on the filter.

```
/**
 * Determine whether the metadataStore should be flushed on each update (if {@link Flushable}).
 * @param flushOnUpdate true to flush.
 * @since 4.1.5
 */
public void setFlushOnUpdate(boolean flushOnUpdate) {
    this.flushOnUpdate = flushOnUpdate;
}
```

Comment: But today I restarted the tomcat service and still there was no change in either the no. of rows or file modified date.

The property file has been updated in June. One of the files which has been fetched twice exist in the property file though not files are in there. 

What exactly is flushed to the property file? All the files that have been read or the last read file?

Comment: The store holds an in-memory map of the properties file; the whole map is flushed when the application context is `close()`d normally (via `DisposableBean.destroy()`. When `fliushOnUpdate` is true in the filter, the map is flushed each time a new file is added. Note that the filter will pass a file if the file's timestamp changes.

Comment: Thank you for detail responses. I checked the ftp server and the file is not updated. All files are appended with created date and have same as modified date. As we are not calling close() explicitly, I am assuming that spring boot/tomcat calls it. The service restarted without any errors in the log files. Still the problem persists.

Comment: If it's a web application context; tomcat should close it normally. If you can reproduce it with a small test case we can take a look.

Comment: Yes, it is a web application context. I am trying to create test for it but not successful yet. May be the duplication parameters are not same in test environment.